# Azure error "Your certificate file was invalid, or the password was incorrect" loading certificate into portal

Tags: azure-keyvault

I generated a public_privatekey.pfx via the [xero instructions](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api-guides/create-publicprivate-key) and was able to access a Xero demo file from a Visual Studio solution that used Xerp.Api.Sdk.Core

Now I want to put the certificate in an Azure Key Vault so that I can port my code to an Azure Function App.

However when I try to use the Azure Portal to load the certificate via

Create a secret -> Certificates ->Create a certificate

I get an error

```
Your certificate file was invalid, or the password was incorrect
```

I can load the certificate using Powershell.

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount -tenantid mytenantid
$pfxFilePath = 'C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\AzureXeroSync\public_privatekey.pfx'
$pwd = 'mypassword'
$flag = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable
$collection = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection 
$collection.Import($pfxFilePath, $pwd, $flag)
$pkcs12ContentType = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12
$clearBytes = $collection.Export($pkcs12ContentType)
$fileContentEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($clearBytes)
$secret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $fileContentEncoded -AsPlainText –Force
$secretContentType = 'application/x-pkcs12'
Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'MyAzureFunctionsVault' -Name 'XeroPfxSecret' -SecretValue $Secret -ContentType $secretContentType
```

what am I missing using the portal ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/about-keys-secrets-and-certificates

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned this in your question:

> Create a secret -> Certificates ->Create a certificate

[image]

I think the issue here is that you're starting with "Create a secret". Uploading/Importing a certificate as a secret is a deprecated feature as you can see in screenshot.

Can you try doing the same thing, but starting from "Certificates" and then do an import instead?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was hopeful, but this method fails for me also with the same message.

Comment: If you have a different pfx.. even self signed would do.. try with that to see if problem is specific to a particular cert or happens for all. Btw, same steps worked for me but not sure of the difference.

Comment: How can I get a different pfx?
I made this one using http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html, the 64bit win version. Can you suggest a different way?

Comment: That should work. Make sure you import it into your windows Certificate Store as well, just to ensure there isn't anything wrong with the generated certificate.

Comment: oh dear, any hints on how to do that? I ran mmc -> add or remove snap in -> certificates but could not see how to import the file.

Comment: add snap in for your user.. then expand personal and right click to see import option..

Comment: The import was successful. Interestingly I had to change the file selector to see the .pfx file, it wanted .cer